Need to style a mapkit JS marker annotation
I have a Mapkit JS map and the marker annotations are interactive, but do not have cursor: pointer style, so I need to add it. The marker annotations are inside a custom element and are in a shadow DOM that cannot be directly styled. I tried:
    const markerContainer = document.querySelector('.mk-annotation-container')
    const style = document.createElement('style')
    style.textContent = `
      .mk-annotations > div {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px red solid; /* for debugging */
      }
    `
    console.log('marker container', markerContainer)
    if (markerContainer && markerContainer.shadowRoot) {
      console.log('success')
      markerContainer.shadowRoot.appendChild(style)
    }

The marker container log shows #shadow-root (closed) inside the container when I expand it, but "success" never logs. This aligns with what I've read, that you cannot access or modify a closed shadow root. Additionally, the Mapkit marker documentation does not provide any way to add styles to this type of annotation. Are there any other options available to me here?

You are correct you can not access closed shadowRoots. Contact the vendor; the least they should/could do is add shadowparts so you can use CSS :part notation

I posted feedback to Apple, and I got a response. Using the map reference, you can get references to the annotation elements and style them. Their example:
map.annotations[0].element.style.width = "100%";
map.annotations[0].element.style.height = "100%";
map.annotations[0].element.style.cursor = "pointer";

My implementation:
function styleAnnotations() {
    map.annotations.forEach((annotation) => {
      annotation.element.style.cursor = 'pointer'
      annotation.element.style.width = '30px'
      annotation.element.style.height = '40px'
      annotation.element.style.margin = '0 auto'
    })
  }

